# Unlocking file in PHP returns true when it shouldn't?

Tags: php, fopen

In PHP, I have created an advisory lock using flock like this:

```
$fileHandle = fopen($filePath, 'c');
flock($fileHandle, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);
```

Running the same code in another process will subsequently fail since the lock is exclusive. But the second process *is* able to run:

```
$fileHandle = fopen($filePath, 'c');
flock($fileHandle, LOCK_UN); // returns true
```

The file is still locked though, as confirmed by running a third process. So why does the unlocking request return true?

Answer (score 0):

While the [**PHP Manual page about `flock()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) seems ambiguous on this front, I would suggest that the return `true` would be because the function *executed successfully*, rather than because any file was locked or unlocked successfully.

Please also note that the [**PHP Manual page**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) shows a lot of caveats regarding this function and I would go so far as to suggest digging out an alternative routine to lock out access to a file.